# How to Merge Two Replace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, replace, web-developer-toolbar

```
var price = "19,99 $"
price.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '').replace(",",".");
console.log(price)

output
19.99
```

- but I need to replace two replace operations with a single replace!
  is it possible?

Comment: What you've shown as the output of the above isn't, because you never assign back to `price`. `replace` *returns* the result, it doesn't modify the string in place. (Strings are immutable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible*, but it may not be worthwhile. You have to pass a function as the second argument:

```js
var price = "19,99 $";
price = price.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, m => m === "," ? "." : "");
console.log(price);
```

I removed `,` from the negated character class, then in the callback checked to see if the match was a `,` and returned `"."` if so, `""` if not. Also note assigning the result back to `price` (your original wasn't, it was throwing away the result).

Comment: without function using or operator can we do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could get all digits and join with dot.

```js
var price = "19,99 $"
price = price.match(/\d+/g).join('.');

console.log(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace anything that `is not 0-9 and , with " ".`After that `split` the string with `comma as separator` and `join with dot`.

```js
const price = "19,99 $"
const result = price.replace(/[^0-9,]/g,"").split(",").join(".");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's too large